# jquery element cross fade plugin

Tags: jquery, fade

I'm looking for a plugin that, ideally, just fades one element into another.  Not just images.

It seems that every plugin out there is a) image specific or b) a full-on, bloated, slideshow plugin.

Is there anything that just takes two arguments, and fades one into the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can write an utility method like this

```
  $.fadeReplace = function($from, $to){
     $from.fadeOut(500, function(){
       $(this).replaceWith($to);
        $to.fadeIn(500);
     });   
  }
```

Usage

```
$.fadeReplace($("#div1"), $("#div2"));
```

Comment: This doesn't cross fade the elements. Thanks though!